# Can you apply shaders to Netflix?

Tags: video, media-player-classic

Is there any way to apply shaders to Netflix? When I use Media Player Classic Home Cinema (MPC-HC) I like the [hlsl matrix filter](https://github.com/dinfinity/mpc-pixel-shaders/blob/master/PS_Matrix.hlsl) for improving older, low resolution content. Is there any sort of process for applying an hlsl or other shader to Netflix?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try an alternative player that provides shader options and shows streamed content? For example, the excellent Daum PotPlayer here > https://potplayer.daum.net/

Within PotPlayer, try right clicking the video and choose Video > Pixel Shader - you will be presented with various gamma, SMPTE and HDR corrections etc and you may find something useful there? BTW, I've found that viewing video in Full Screen Exclusive mode (see Preferences > Video) applies chosen settings better - ymmv.

Hope helps :)